# Measures traffic on piranha cms web

Tags: c#, .net, logging, metrics, piranha-cms

I'm looking for a way to get the traffic (some metics) of a personal piranha cms web site.

The straightforward method used so far is a custom middleware.
It was easy to cast the incoming request info (host, url requested, agent,...) into a dedicated database. Additional dev might be needed : current result for url is something like `/archive?id=86b449a5-0e65-4104-b81f-64d252568089&startpage=true` rather that the real title of the page.

**What would be a better way to procced ?**

Here is my research so far :

- There is no ressouces about getting trafic info Piranha CMS documentation.
- There is no result when update the log details using appsetting.json (`..."LogLevel": {"Default": "Trace"...`)
- There is 'build-in' razor solution with Google Analytics (see [Tracking Visitor Information (Analytics) for an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/performance-and-traffic/14-analyzing-traffic)).
- There is also log from another software (load balancer / apache accces log)

**Any suggestion ?**

The final idea might be to add this trafic data into the Piranha CMS repo as dashboard. There is no relativ issue (past and present) about it; it might be a good feature.

Let me know,